# A partial differential equation with solution in a Sobolev space with a "weight"

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I am studying the book Wong, introduction pseudo differential operators and I have a question regarding the Sobolev space and how domain can be used to solve a partial differential equation.

For each $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the equation
\begin{align}
(I-\partial_x^2)u(x)=f(x)
\end{align}
has a solution $u$ in $H^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ given that
\begin{align}
u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+\xi^2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)
\end{align}
Here, $H^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ is
\begin{align}
H^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})=\left\{u \text{ tempered distribution }: \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+\xi^2)^{1/2}\widehat{u}(\xi)\right)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\right\}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(I-\partial_x^2)u(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{u}(\xi))](x)
\end{align}

My question is:

If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the equation
\begin{align}
(1+x^2)(I-\partial_x^2)u(x)=f(x)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
(1+x^2)(I-\partial_x^2)u(x)=(1+x^2)\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{u}(\xi))(x)
\end{align}
has a unique solution $u\in H_{1+x^2}^{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$ where

\begin{align}H_{1+x^2}^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}):=\left\{u\text{ tempered distribution }: (1+x^2)\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+\xi^2)\widehat{u}(\xi))(x) \text{ in } L^2(\mathbb{R})\right\}\end{align}
given that

\begin{align}
u(x)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}\right)(\xi)\right)(x)
\end{align}?